# Причина ошибки?

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in H:\OSPanel\domains\KingKino\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 H:\OSPanel\domains\KingKino\index.php(18): ClassName::lol() #1 {main} thrown in H:\OSPanel\domains\KingKino\index.php on line 13

```
class AnotherClass
{
public $name = 'hoh';
public static function ff () {
echo $this->name;
}

}
class ClassName extends AnotherClass
{
public static function lol () {
    echo $this->name;

}
}
$us = new ClassName();
$us::lol();
```

https://ideone.com/8OR80j

Answer (score 1):

Метод `lol` статический, поэтому экземпляра класса там нет.

Comment: То есть в статические методы нельзя присваивать свойства или методы других классов ?

Comment: @HellMenDos, [можно](https://ideone.com/btxpS2). Просто у вас гремучая смесь синтаксиса.

Comment: @Deonis, но `self` - это не `$this`.

Comment: @Deonis, и вообще, пиши ответ)